# How to Import a table from web in Excel from a cell contains URL?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a data table from a web, based on the year I select.

eg. 
"https://www.boxofficemojo.com/daily/2016/?interval=may&view=month"

"https://www.boxofficemojo.com/daily/"&A3&"/?interval=may&view=month"

A3 contains a list of years (eg. 2014, 2015)

Without using a method of DATA > New Query > From Web > copy & paste the link

Is there any way to replicate the same result with VBA / Macro?

I'd like to see the newly updated table on B1 once a year from A3 is selected then refreshed

Comment: Please do not include a link to your macro enabled workbook - It's unlikely anyone will download it anyway is it can be dangerous - instead, include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: try this .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGw6r5GVA5g&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=68